# Pandas: Merging two header rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dataset, netcdf4

I'm currently working with some netCDF4 files and trying to get them into pandas to ease further manipulation. Here's some context on how the NC Datasets are being read and created:

```
vwnd_ds = xr.open_dataset('data/vwnd/vwnd.10m.daily2016.nc')
```

The Datasets are then converted to Dataframes:

```
vwnd_speed = vwnd_ds.to_dataframe()
```

This yields the following Dataframe with two row headers:

```
vwnd_speed
```

|  |  |  |  | vwnd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **level** | **lat** | **lon** | **time** |  |
| *data* | *data* | *data* | *data* | *data* |
| *data* | *data* | *data* | *data* | *data* |

This represents a problem when trying to access or filter out data from specific columns, since pandas only seems to recognize the first header "vwnd". I'm trying to merge both row headers into something like:

| level | lat | lon | time | vwnd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| *data* | *data* | *data* | *data* | *data* |
| *data* | *data* | *data* | *data* | *data* |

so that I'm able to use pandas to further manipulate these Dataframes.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: is pandas converting the table to a multi-index dataframe? or the second level of columns are in a row?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, it looks like your messed up dataframe actually has a header, but the first few column names are just blanks.  What you can do to solve this is to rename the columns with the names you want them to be and just drop the first row that has the column names partially in there.  Something like this...

```py
df = df.drop([0])
df.columns = ['level', 'lat', 'lon', 'time', 'vwnd']
```